# Android custom notification sound

Tags: android, audio, notifications

I have to change notification sound in my app. The sound is downloaded from the server so it is stored in my app storage. Unfortunately, the sound is not played.

```
File folder = new File(context.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "sounds");
File sound = new File(folder, "my-sound.mp3");

Notification notification = new Builder(context)
            .setContentText("test")
            .setContentTitle(context.getText(R.string.app_name))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setSound(Uri.parse(sound.toString()))
            .build();
```

I also tried to get this `Uri` differently:

```
.setSound(Uri.parse(sound.toString()))
```

Or save it in `MediaStore`:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, sound.getAbsolutePath());
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, "My Song title");
values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "Some Artist");
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, false);
values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(sound.getAbsolutePath());
Uri soundUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
```

Sound Uri path is now equal `content://media/external/audio/media/1265` and still its not working.

If I set default sound then it is working correctly. `.setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(TYPE_NOTIFICATION))`

Comment: Check file is not corrupted. may be during download process its got corrupted.

Comment: File is not corrupted

Comment: I always get null as result from context.getContentResolver().insert()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For files stored in Internal Storage you can use FileProvider.

Add provider to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<provider
    android:authorities="my.file.provider"
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

then add new xml file with body

```
<paths>
    <files-path name="sounds" path="sounds/"/>
</paths>
```

before setSound  you have to grandUriPermission to Android System

```
Uri soundUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "my.file.provider", sound);
context.grantUriPermission("com.android.systemui", soundUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

...

.setSound(soundUri)
```

Comment: What is the last param of getUriForFile() stands for?

Comment: It is `File` object for file you want to give access to

Comment: I get `Caused by java.lang.SecurityException
UID 10454 does not have permission to content://media/external/audio/media/4590`

Comment: Android must be the most fragile software platform out there!  Anything can catastrophically crash each time a new Android version comes out...

Answer (score 1):

> For Custom Sound Use this

```
NotificationCompat.Builder  mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
     mBuilder.setSound(Uri.parse("uri://sadfasdfasdf.mp3"));
```

> for Default Notification sound use this

```
Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        mBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);
```